# QT Creator compiler and debugger showing different types for same variable

Tags: c++, qt-creator

```
template<typename T>
class TD;

struct foo {
    float bar(float a, float b) { return a*b; }
};

...

auto p = &foo::bar;    // [1]
//TD<decltype(p)> fpType;    // [2]
```

With line 2 commented out, QT Creator 4.8.0 shows p as type `float (foo::*)(foo * const, float, float)` in the debugger.
With line 2 uncommented, the compiler error shows p as type `float (foo::*)(float, float)`.

I think the correct type is `float (foo::*)(float, float)` so is this a QT Creator bug?

The compiler is G++ 7.3.0.

Comment: any member function gets an implicit `this` pointer passed which is probably what you see in the debugger.

Comment: use ` for code, not '

Comment: @MooingDuck: No, I think `foo * const` would be the correct type for the `this` pointer.

Comment: @SirVisto: I was thinking of `const foo*`, my mistake.